# jQuery toggle of next div with this class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve a toggle effect on a website. 
The html looks like this:

```
<div class="prod-toggle-click">
  <h2>Test</h2>
    <div class="prod-toggle">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="prod-toggle-click">
  <h2>Test 2</h2>
   <div class="prod-toggle">
    <p>test 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
<script>
$(".prod-toggle-click").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.prod-toggle').toggle();
});
</script>
```

This toggles the `.prod-toggle` of both divs. But I only need the `.prod-toggle` of the parent to toggle.

I've tried it like this:

```
<script>
$(".prod-toggle-click").click(function(){
    $(this).next('.prod-toggle').slideToggle();
});
</script>
```

but that's not working either. Any suggestions?

Comment: $(".prod-toggle-click").click(function(){
    $(this).children('.prod-toggle').slideToggle();
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `find('.prod-toggle')` and remove the `parent()` or `next()` which you are using. This is because the `div` with class `prod-toggle` is inside the `div` with class `prod-toggle-click` so `find()` will simply work for you here.

```js
$(".prod-toggle-click").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.prod-toggle').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prod-toggle-click">
  <h2>Test</h2>
    <div class="prod-toggle">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="prod-toggle-click">
  <h2>Test 2</h2>
   <div class="prod-toggle">
    <p>test 2</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need put this under $(document).ready and also remove parent()

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".prod-toggle-click").click(function(){
    $(this).find('.prod-toggle').toggle();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For this specific case, I would use `children()` instead of `find()`. It only looks at the immediate children of the node. It is more explicit and that's the reason of my preference. I guess performance is not an issue but `children()` should also be faster.

```
$(".prod-toggle-click").click(function(){
    $(this).children(".prod-toggle").toggle();
});
```